# SSH ключи генерация

Tags: linux, ssh, администрирование, ssh-key

У меня один сервер Linux, и несколько клиентов.

Задача: подключаться по SSH с помощью ключей.

Понимание: Я должен генерировать ключи на клиентах, и публичный ключ копировать на сервер.

Вопрос:

1. Можно ли на основе одного приватного ключа на сервере, генерить разные публичные ключи и раздать клиентам? Ведь при новом ssh-keygen создается новая пара, а старая удаляется?
2. На хосте делаю новую пару ключей, то на сервера я кидаю один и тот же публичный ключ или можно генерить разные на основе одного приватного?

Спасибо за ранее!

Answer (score 0):

1. Тело вопроса противоречит порядку использования SSH. Принято, что клиенту необходимо у себя сгенерировать ключи и публичный уже любым способом залить на сервер. Либо сгенерировать можно вам, а потом выдать клиенту приватный ключ. На сервере должен быть **публичный** ключ. При *ssh-keygen* у клиента другая пара может и затрется, если название и расположение нового ключа будет совпадать со старым. Но вообще, при создании новых ключей со старыми ничего не происходит. Насчёт сервера, то при добавлении нового публичного ключа ничего не удалится. Новый публичный ключ просто заносится в `authorized keys` новой строчкой
2. Заливать публичный ключ на сервер требуется от **каждой** пары.

[Очень полезный цикл статей по SSH](https://hackware.ru/?p=10059)

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.